# MIX seqbuilder [CustomOperation] attribute method AND vanilla yield IN a single seq expression

Tags: f#

This code runs fine except if I uncomment the last line in my custom seq expression :

```
type T (i: int) = 
    member x.i = i
    override x.ToString() =
        sprintf "T is %A " x.i

type TBuilder() =
    member x.Yield (()) = Seq.empty

    [<CustomOperation("test")>]
    member x.Test1 (source : seq<_>, i: int) : seq<T> =
        printfn "Calling Test1 with i= %d" i |> ignore
        seq { yield! source
              yield T(i) }

let t = TBuilder()

let mytest = 
    t {
        test 42
        test 43
//        yield T(44)  // if uncommented, it does not compile
    }
```

If `yield T(44)` line is uncommented, I get an compiler error like so :

```
Error   This control construct may only be used if the computation expression builder defines a 'For' method.
```

My **question** : Is there a way to mix

- my [CustomOperation] *test* (from method  **Test1**) that yields T objects

with

- a vanilla yield, for example `yield T(44)` or any other seq related syntax

inside a unique seq expression BUT without defining any 'For' method ?

Reference : DSL in Action for F# (Chapter 7) by Anh-Dung Phan on [github](https://github.com/dungpa/dsls-in-action-fsharp/blob/master/Chapter7/Order.Fsharp.fs).
Thanks.

Comment: Why your Yield member takes a unit? I'd assume it should take T value.

Comment: @Bartek ; Yield was defined like this in the reference cited. It returns an empty seq to initialize a seq and then Test1 method gets all the source yielded so far and adds another element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.  If you change your operators so that they preserve variable bindings (via `MaintainsVariableSpace=true` or `MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind=true` arguments to the `[<CustomOperator>]` attribute constructor) then you won't need `For` but you'll need `Bind` instead.

What do you expect the computation expression you've written to *mean*?  If you look at how the F# spec specifies the translation for computation expressions, anything of the form

```
bldr {
  op1 x
  op2 y
  yield z
}
```

will turn into something like

```
bldr.For(bldr.Op2(bldr.Op1(bldr.Yield(), x), y), fun () -> b.Yield(z))
```

so you clearly need a `For` method and also your `Yield` method needs to do something different; at the very least it needs to be able to take arguments of arbitrary types (e.g. in the above example it needs to work on an argument of type `unit` and also on an argument of whatever type the value `z` has).